# Dynamic class for Meteor Event Map

Tags: jquery, events, meteor

I am trying to create a wizard package and can't seem to be able to setup a click event on an element.

I want the person using the package to be able to define their next and previous buttons class values and then apply an event when an element with those classes are clicked.

It works fine when I use static class values but if I try to use the ones I define when I initialize the wizard it fails with an unexpected token value. I have tried printing the classes to the console within the events function and they are printing out fine.

This works fine but uses a static class name

```
Template.wizard.events({
  "click .btn-prev": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.wizard.previous();
  }
});
```

This won't work with `unexpected token +` error

```
Template.wizard.events({
  "click ." + this.wizard.prevClass: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.wizard.prev();
  }
});
```

I then tried to get around it by doing something like this but my if statement always seems to return false.

```
Template.wizard.events({
  'click': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass(this.wizard.nextClass)){
      this.wizard.next();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is supposed to be your `$(this)`? You are in the callback of a click :)

If you want to find something after a click, you should try with the event current target (not the target, they could be different), or the second argument of the click (the template) :

```
Template.wizard.events({
    'click': function (e, tmpl) {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(e.currentTarget);
        console.log(tmpl);
        console.log(tmpl.find(this.wizard.nextClass);

        if( e.currentTarget.className === this.wizard.nextClass )
            this.wizard.next();

    }
});
```